# How to minimize switch statement?

Tags: javascript

I am using switch statement to handle over 20 cases. It there a way to minimize a long switch statement for e.g as given below:

```
switch (something) {

    case 1:
        doX();
    break;

    case 2:
        doY();
    break;

    case 3:
        doN();
    break;

    // And so on...

}
```

**Edit:**

As all are asking I have to clarify that this is a javascript question.

Comment: That would depend entirely on what you're actually doing. Based solely on the pseudo-code you have given, no. If you post a [mcve], maybe.

Comment: There are many ways to do this; but without more context (ie, more code), it will be difficult to provide a suitable answer.

Comment: @EdCottrell thanks for the guidance. Actually I used pseudo-code because my actual switch statement is very long. I thought it would have complicated the question

Comment: is it related to java or javascript it is confusing? If it is related to Java what is the expected version?

Comment: Please stop downvoting my question i tagged it clearly as jave but @fge removed javascript tag and made my question complicated. Please don't be so unjust.

Comment: Wait; JavaScript and Java are clearly two very different languages. Why tag it Java if it is JavaScript? This is not a question of being unjust here, it's a question of accuracy. The amount of people still mixing between those two languages in 2016 is nothing short of staggering. To quote an anonymous source, Java is to Javascript what a car is to a carpet. They have nothing in common _at all_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have provide only a pseudo-code. You should have provide your actual code so that I may have guided you better. Anyhow you may use the following short form for your long swith statement.

```
var cases = {
    1: doX,
    2: doY,
    3: doN
    //......................cases from 4 to 19
    20: doZ
};
if (cases[something]) {
    cases[something]();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Its exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @toweddeji-2389 this seems to be javascript not java, which language do you expect as answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can if there are some cases for which task is same. For example: if for both case 1 and case 10 same method `doX()` happens, you could do this:

```
switch (something) {

    case 1:
    case 10:
        doX();
    break;

    //...

}
```

Furthermore, if you have a common task that you would be done for many cases like for case - 12, 13, 14, 15 and 16, `doA()` will be executed. Let it be for `default` case. It will lessen writing many cases.

```
switch (something) {

    // for case 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
    default:
        doA();
    break;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Actually all the cased are different.

Answer (score 0):

You might use ES6 Map functionality to create a map of your functions then you just need to call it with the dynamic key value.

```js
var myMap = new Map(),
      doX = n => console.log(n),
      doY = n => console.log(n*2),
      doN = n => console.log(n/2),
something = 2;
      
myMap.set(1,doX)
     .set(2,doY)
     .set(3,doN);
myMap.get(something)(4);
```

The same could be implemented by an ordinary object as well like

```js
var myMap = {},
      doX = n => console.log(n),
      doY = n => console.log(n*2),
      doN = n => console.log(n/2),
something = 3;
      
myMap[1] = doX;
myMap[2] = doY;
myMap[3] = doN;
myMap[something](4);
```

Comment: this is javascript too while the question has been tagged with java

Comment: @Nicolas Filotto wow.. i could swear this question was resulted on a JavaScript query. Anyways got to delete it then.

Comment: @Redu you are right, I've just checked the history of the question, there was the tag javascript at the very beginning and it has not been removed by the OP so your answer may be valid